# How to make prepareForSegue with UIcollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have problem with this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailsSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailsSegue" {
        let detailsVC: DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as! NSIndexPath
         var thisCoupon = self.userCoupons[indexPath.row] as UserCoupons
         detailsVC.userCoupon = self.userCoupons[indexPath.row]
        detailsVC.pinArray = self.pinArray
        detailsVC.userStamp = self.userStamps[indexPath.row]

    }

}
```

When I have only one item in collection view I can't go to DetailsViewController. When I have few items, my segue works with items without last item.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.userCoupons.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StampsCollectionViewCell

    let thisStamp = self.userCoupons[indexPath.row]

    if thisStamp.couponImage != nil {
        var image = thisStamp.couponImage
        cell.stampImage.image = image
    }

    var day: NSString = (thisStamp.couponDate as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 6), withString: "")
    var monthS: NSString = (thisStamp.couponDate as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 4), withString: "")
    var month:  NSString = monthS.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSRange(location: 2, length: 2), withString: "")
    var year: NSString = (thisStamp.couponDate as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSRange(location: 4, length: 4), withString: "")

    cell.stampDate.text = "\(day).\(month).\(year)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Still last item isn't working.

Comment: are you getting any error on that line?

Comment: I have error here:             let indexPaths = self.couponsCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() 

EXC_BAD_INTRODUCTION green error. I have 3 items. Item 1 and 2 works great, I have error only on item 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code should work well for you :

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetailsSegue" {

          let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
          let cell = sender as! StampsCollectionViewCell
          let indexPaths = self.couponsCollectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)
          var thisCoupon = self.userCoupons[indexPaths!.row] as UserCoupons
          detailsVC.userCoupon = thisCoupon
          detailsVC.pinArray = self.pinArray
          detailsVC.userStamp = self.userStamps[indexPaths!.row]

    }

}
```

**Update :** Please check the incoming data from the server if its correct or not and it might work !

Comment: Still not working:

Could not cast value of type 'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x1043047f0) to 'MyCollectionViewCell' (0x105ea1008).

Comment: do you have a custom cell ?

Comment: Yes. Named: MyCollectionViewCell

Comment: then change CollectionViewCell to MyCollectionViewCell and let me know !

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x1016c8940) to 'AppTest.StampsCollectionViewCell' (0x1016c75b0). Green SIGABRT.

Comment: Yes but It still not working. You have error here:  'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x1016c8940) to 'AppTest.StampsCollectionViewCell' (0x1016c75b0). Green SIGABRT

Comment: @Maselko , are you still having the same issue ?

Comment: Yes, it still not working. Now I'm trying to make new CollectionViewController...

Comment: @Maselko, if you may send me a sample project and ill fix the issue or lets keep solving it here ! let me know please :)

Comment: Please give me your mail. Its private project. And many thanks for help! :D

Comment: Ok, delete. And give me 5 min :)

Comment: @Aaoli please let me know if you will find issue.

Comment: Sure i will email you with it ! @Maselko

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let cell = sender as StampsCollectionViewCell
let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)
```

And your code will be:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 

{
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailsSegue" {
        let detailsVC: DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
        let cell = sender as StampsCollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)
        var thisCoupon = self.userCoupons[indexPath.row] as UserCoupons
        detailsVC.userCoupon = thisCoupon
        detailsVC.pinArray = self.pinArray
        detailsVC.userStamp = self.userStamps[indexPath.row]

    }

}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Green SIGABRT on  let cell = sender as! StampsCollectionViewCell and Could not cast value of type 'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x10c9d8940) to 'AppTest.StampsCollectionViewCell' (0x10c9d75b0).

Comment: can you share sample project?

Comment: what is `StampsCollectionViewCell `?

Comment: This is my custom CollectionViewCell

Comment: so do sender as StampsCollectionViewCell gosh !

Comment: Guys I made it. It doesn't work.            let cell = sender as! StampsCollectionViewCell here is green SIGABRT and I can see in console: Could not cast value of type 'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x100376940) to 'AppTest.StampsCollectionViewCell' (0x1003755b0).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailsSegue", sender: cell)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailsSegue" {
        let detailsVC: DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
        let cell = sender as! StampsCollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)
        var thisCoupon = self.userCoupons[indexPath.row] as UserCoupons
        detailsVC.userCoupon = thisCoupon
        detailsVC.pinArray = self.pinArray
        detailsVC.userStamp = self.userStamps[indexPath.row]

    }

}
```

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x10c30c940) to 'NSIndexPath' (0x10cd5c680).

Comment: The sender is `cell` not `self`.

Comment: Green error on:             let cell = sender as! StampsCollectionViewCell and in console Could not cast value of type 'AppTest.SecondViewController' (0x1014c5950) to 'AppTest.StampsCollectionViewCell' (0x1014c45c0).

Comment: How do you set the `showDetailsSegue` segue in storyboard?

Comment: Yes I have. Segue works great. I can see in DetailsVC items from collection view index: 0, 1, 2. But I have 4 items, and last item generate error.

Comment: Can you post your code about `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `numberOfItemsInSection`?