# Passing an array of structs from UICollectionView to DetailView and use the indexes to go from one item to another?

Tags: swift, struct, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, detailview

I have a UICollectionView that is populated by an array of productItem structs, the struct blueprint is in it's own swift file called ProductoItem.swift

```
struct ProductoItem {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var price: String
    var picture: String
    var description: String
}
```

This works and I can successfully populate my UICollectionView with it, what I want to do now is to pass this struct to a detailView so I create this variable in the detailView.

```
var productos = [ProductoItem]()
```

And I put the following code in my prepareForSegue Method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detalleProducto" {

        let controller = segue.destination as! ProductoDetailViewController

        controller.productos = productos
    }
}
```

What I don't know how to do know is:

First as we are sending the entire array of structs I want to pass the values stored on the CollectionView cell's index to the DetailView to populate it using just the data of the product's cell, then I also want to have two buttons to go to the next / prev product that just go to the next / prev index value of my struct. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you use "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" to open your detailView?

Comment: In the prepare you can get the index of the cell that was pressed yourCollectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)  and then get the data from the array with index.  Check out this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914213/how-to-make-prepareforsegue-with-uicollectionview

Comment: @RemyCilia yes I do, and if instead of using a struct I use an array of dictionaries I can get the current indexpath by doing this.

let currentProduct = arrayOfDictionaries[indexPath.item] but when I try the same using the struct I get an empty array.

Anyway when I was using an array of dictionaries I could get the objects of one product doing that method, but what I need is to bring the entire struct, use the values in the index of the selected cell to populate the detailView, in this view I have two buttons to go to the next / prev product so when you click them the index changes)

Comment: @Yan I can get the index of the cell that was pressed by doing this in the prepare(for segue:) method: 

let item = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems 

But what I need is to use that indexPath with my struct array so when I go to the detail view the struct picked to populate the data is the one selected. Once there I need to be able to go to the next or previous index values so I can switch to the next / previous products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new 'currentIndex: Int' attribute in your detailView.

From your first UIViewController (the one that has the UICollectionView), pass the current index and the array to your DetailView:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detalleProducto" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! ProductoDetailViewController
        controller.productos = productos

        // do whatever you need to get your index
        controller.currentIndex = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()[0].row
    }
}
```

Then in your DetailView, you have your array and the current index, so you can just get the info of this specific product by doing:

```
let currentProduct = self.productos[currentIndex]
```

To get to the previous or next one, you can just increment or decrement 'currentIndex'.

Comment: It worked perfectly, I didn't thank you before because I was on holidays, but your solution was great, thanks