# collection view cells fetch data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to collection view. I want to retrieve data from CoreData for collection view cell. I know how to retrieve for table view cell but it failed when I use similar way to fetch for collection view. Here are my functions from CoreDataHelper and ViewController class

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "displayCellDetail" {
            print("Task View cell tapped")


      CollectionViewCoreDataHelper.retrieveTasks()


    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!

         let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    let TaskSettingViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

           TaskSettingViewController.task = task

        } else if identifier == "addTask" {
            print("+ button tapped")
        }
    }
}


static func retrieveTasks() -> [Tasks] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Tasks>(entityName: "Tasks")
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error)")
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your flow for facing data. but general from is first fact the data and then you need to display it to your collection view if data is exist

Comment: and make sure first you are getting something from retrieveToDo and after that don't forgot to reload the colectionview

Comment: the collection cell view can load successfully but I want the data inside the cell can be displayed in my detail view(2 views). I use breakpoint to check and I know the CoreData saved the information I want.

Comment: does data pass from first to second view correcly?

Comment: I feel this is my problem! I don't actually know how to pass data for collection view.

Comment: create variable with same type to second view which you want to pass it from second. i.e [ToDo]

Comment: I already did them but seems not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  :

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            if identifier == "displayCellDetail" {
                print("Task View cell tapped")

      CollectionViewCoreDataHelper.retrieveTasks()

      let cell = sender as? YourCellName //Cell from which this segue is being performed
      let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)               
      let task  = self.tasks[indexPath.item] //Downcast to type of  task

      let objTaskSettingVC = segue.destination as! TaskSettingViewController 

           objTaskSettingVC.tasks = task 

        } 
    else if identifier == "addTask" {
            print("+ button tapped")
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'indexPathForSelectedItem'

Comment: maybe it's because I use a collection view inside a view controller?

Comment: In storyboard make segue from your cell, this will make the sender as your cell, currently I think you are using segue from the controller

Answer (score 0):

For passing the data from one viewController to other is here

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "displayCellDetail" {
            print("Task View cell tapped")

  CollectionViewCoreDataHelper.retrieveTasks()
       let cell = sender as UICollectionViewCell
       let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)
       let task  = self.tasks[indexPath.row] as [ToDo]

       let objTaskSettingVC = segue.destination as! TaskSettingViewController // ViewController in which you want to send the data

       objTaskSettingVC.tasks = [task] //tasks is your variable which is having same type and defined in your TaskSettingViewController 

    } 
else if identifier == "addTask" {
        print("+ button tapped")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a error appearing. "Value of type '[IndexPath]' has no member 'row'.

Comment: So I should change 'row' to item?   "let task = tasks[indexPath.row]"

Comment: the problem changes to  "Value of type '[IndexPath]' has no member 'item'.

Comment: Sorry. It changes to '[IndexPath]' has no member 'objectAtIndex'.

Comment: can you please create chat room so we can discuss it over there

Comment: try indexPath!.item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914213/how-to-make-prepareforsegue-with-uicollectionview

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a chat room @ Maddyヅヅ

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/150117/collection-view-cells-fetch-data?tab=general

Comment: I don't have 20 reputations so I can't even edit text.@Maddyヅヅ

Comment: cannot convert value of type 'Tasks' to Type 'ViewController' in coercion @user1000

Comment: Have you tried Maddy's code and what is the error for this?

Comment: Yes. Here is the error a another error "could not cast value of type 'collectionVIew.ViewController' (0x103d3fcb0) to 'collectionVIew.MyCollectionViewCell' (0x103d3fe88)." @user1000

Comment: that mean sender as UICollectionViewCell should be sender as MyCollectionViewCell

Comment: I changed to" let cell = sender as! MyCollectionViewCell
            
                let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPath(for: cell)"     the error is "Could not cast value of type 'collectionVIew.ViewController' (0x109eec280) to 'collectionVIew.MyCollectionViewCell' (0x109eec648)."